# how to graph Z on the (x, y) plane and how to find the cdf of Z?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

We consider a random point $(X, Y)$ chosen with the following joiint density
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2y^2},  & \text{if } x \ge 1 \text{ and } y \ge 1 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
Consider another random variable Z=XY.
A. for $z \gt 1$ make a plot of the region in the $(x, y)$ plane given by
{$(x,y): xy \le z $} $\cap$ {$x \ge 1$} $\cap$ {$y \ge 1$}

B. Use the previous question to compute the cdf of Z.

For some reason I can't remember how to graph something that involves x and y, I decided to to get the equation in terms of x and then y and I got $y=\frac1x$ and $x=\frac1y$, but aren't these the same thing? is the answer to A. just the graph of $y=\frac1x$ starting from $x=1$ to $\infty$ and $y=1$ to $\infty$? I got the possible values of Z as $Z \ge 1$ if that helps, and I think X and Y are independent.
For B I think I know how to do the integration, but I just do not know how to set it up?

Comment: $y \ge$ what?..

Comment: sorry, it's $y \ge 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha gives us bounds. Try changing 2 with different numbers $>1$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%20%3C%3D%202%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20y%20%3D%3E%201).

So we have

$$F_Z(z) = P(Y - \frac{z}{X} \le 0) = \int_1^z \int_1^{z/x} \frac{1}{x^2y^2}dydx$$

Comment: on wolfram you used $xy \le 2$, why did you substitute $2$ for $z$? and was I correct when I stated that the possible values of $Z$ are $Z \ge 1$?

Comment: @idknuttin No particular reason. I just tried out 2 then 100 then pressed back and copied the link. $Z > 1$.

Comment: Why $Z \ge 1$ when it is given that Z > 1? @idknuttin

Comment: I tried to calculate it, since $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$ then if $Z=XY$, $xy \ge 1*1$ which just equals $z \ge 1$

Comment: the question is asking me to graph in terms of $xy \le z$ but the graph will change depending on what $z$ is right? so can I graph it?

Comment: @idknuttin Ah I see. Well $F_Z(1) = P(Y \le 0) = 0$

Comment: @idknuttin I think A is to help you have an idea of how to set up the integral in computing the cdf of Z. Say $Z=2$, what's the cdf? Then $Z=3$ and so on. Then you see the pattern

Comment: yes, that makes sense, thank you.