# what bounds do I integrate over to find the $cdf$ of $Z=XY$ using the following joint density function

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

what bounds do I integrate over to find the $cdf$ of $Z=XY$ using the following joint density function
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\ xe^{-x(y+1)},  & \text{if}\quad x \gt 0, y \gt 0 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and how did you figure it out because I have no idea how you would graph this?

Comment: We want the probability that $Z\le z$. Let $z\gt 0$ be fixed. **Draw** the curve $xy=z$. We integrate our density function over the part of the first quadrant that is *below* the curve $xy=z$.

Comment: so would the bounds be $\int_0^z \int_0^{z/x} xe^{-x(y+1)} dydx$?

Comment: The density function is "sort of" used to determine the bounds. Specifically, we used the fact that the density function is $0$ outside the first quadrant.

Comment: are my bounds correct?

Comment: @AndréNicolas What is the purpose of 'but x ... to z'? The bounds are indeed correct right? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%20%3C%3D%202%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20y%20%3D%3E%201

Comment: @BCLC: Could be a blind spot, I do get those. But I do not see why limit $x$ to the interval $(0,z)$.  The computer output is nor persuasive, since in the input it was specified that $y\ge 1$, a restriction that is not in the problem.

Comment: I think @AndréNicolas is right: you should have $F_Z(z)=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^{z/x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah I forgot to change from the other problem. thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ummmmm...?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565157/how-to-graph-z-on-the-x-y-plane-and-how-to-find-the-cdf-of-z/1566264#1566264)

---

Wolfram Alpha gives us bounds. Try changing 2 with different numbers $>1$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy+%3C%3D+2%2C+x+%3E0%2C+y+%3E0).

So we have

$$F_Z(z) = P(Y - \frac{z}{X} \le 0) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{z/x} xe^{-x(y+1)} dydx$$

or

$$F_Z(z) = P(Y - \frac{z}{X} \le 0) = \int_{\text{change}} \int_{\text{bounds}} xe^{-x(y+1)} dxdy$$

---

Re the comments in OP:

Suppose we have to integrate $f(x)$ over $[-1,1]$. Then

$$I := \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$$

This is true regardless of whatever $f(x)$ is (provided we can integrate it). However, the bounds might change later on. Suppose we have

$$f(x) = x 1_{\{-1 < x < 0\}}$$

Then we have

$$I = \int_{-1}^1 x 1_{\{-1 < x < 0\}} dx = \int_{-1}^0 x dx + \int_{-1}^0 0 dx = \int_{-1}^0 x dx$$

Comment: I was confused with this and the previous problem that you linked because I did not understand why the bounds were the same when the density functions we were using were different.I didn't understand why the graphs always looked the same if we use different density functions for $f(x.y)$

Comment: @idknuttin Obviously :P But everything's clear now hopefully?

Comment: @BCLC: Sorry about the delay, finally did check. If we integrate $y=0$ to $z/x$, then $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, and it turns out that $Z$ has exponential distribution parameter $1$.

Comment: thank you for confirming the bounds are 0 to $\infty$ but do you know why  for the question that I asked previously that BCLC linked to his answer the bounds are 1 to $z$ and not 1 to $\infty$ even though the graphs are very similar?

Comment: @idknuttin Ah, I see. I forgot to change. The bounds are different than in the other problem

Comment: @AndréNicolas Edited answer

Comment: @idknuttin: For the other problem, the geometry is different. The constraint $y\ge 1$ forces $x$ to be $\le z$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas and idknuttin, edited

Comment: @idknuttin I don't think AndréNicolas was notified of your comment. I think you have to tag him